# I have to get the ticket stamped or punched in the ticket

Tags: word-usage

When entering the bus I have to get the ticket stamped by the device in the bus. Can I say?
I have punched the ticket in or I got the ticket stamped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stamped and punched actually mean different things. Stamping a ticket makes a mark on it with ink, while punching a ticket refers to punching a hole in the paper. These are two different methods of marking a ticket, and a given ticket-taking device on a bus may use either of these. Note that in some other circumstances (such as a movie theater) you may have your ticket *torn* instead of stamped or punched.

It does not sound very natural to say *I have punched the ticket in*. I would say *I got my ticket punched* or *the device punched my ticket*.

Comment: I want to add that in modern times, often ticket's aren't "punched" or "stamped" any more, but the phrase is a holdover from when we did. For example, I've never had an actual punch card, but I've always used the phrase "punched in" for scanning my ID or logging into the computer at work.

Comment: @Sarah good point. I think "punch in"/"punch out" is especially common as an idiomatic expression for signing into or out of work ("punching the clock"). It's in reference to old-fashioned time cards, but I've even heard this used for jobs that aren't hourly.